# Android: How to handle a link clicked on a Text View?

Tags: android, url, textview

I want to be able to handle the case when a user clicks a link in a `TextView`.

With iOS I would simply conform to `UITextViewDelegate` protocol and override the function `textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldInteractWith URL: URL, in characterRange: NSRange) -> Bool`. However, I can't find a solution with Android. So what to do?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

```
    String link = "<a href=http://www.aol.com/>AOL</a>.\n";
    textView.append(Html.fromHtml(link));
    textView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

This should do it.

Make sure your textView has this added to it's XML.

```
android:autoLink="web"
```

Comment: Hi and thanks for your answer. I have actually already added the autolink attribute in the XML, however I’m not sure to understand how I can get the tapped URL and how I can implement a listener afterwards..

Answer (score 0):

**To find a link in TextView simply use in XML:**

```
android:autoLink="web"
```

**Or Progrommatically use this code:**

```
Linkify.addLinks(yourTextview, Linkify.WEB_URLS);
```

**To handle user click on an URL in TextView you can use this library [BetterLinkMovementMethod](https://github.com/Saketme/Better-Link-Movement-Method)**

Answer (score -1):

You can set the click handler in xml with these attribute:

android:onClick="onClick"
android:clickable="true"

And then in your main activity after on create

```
public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, 
        Uri.parse("http://www.google.ca"));
        startActivity(intent);
      }
```